# How to get size file upload firebase swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i used this code for get size file that i upload to firebase

```
let uploadAudio = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("data").child(fileName).putFile(fileSelect, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in            
    print(metadata?.size)
})
```

but that's doesn't works.

Comment: `NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fileSelect,0.5); NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);`

Comment: What did you get with `metadata?.size`?

Comment: i got 0 for metadata?.size

Comment: that is obj-c @EICaptainv2.0 ? can you tell me swift code?